# load facebook's URL feed stream on demand won't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, facebook-like

I am trying to show the facebook feed of my website's URL to show users what facebook users like from my page,

what i do is:

Import facebook's script

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/es_LA/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=82743675977";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

Make the call:

```
function showFeed(){
        return '<div class="box"><h2><img src="http://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=keepourlinks.com"/> keepyourlinks </h2><div class="fb-activity" data-site="keepyourlinks.com" data-width="300" data-height="500" data-header="false" data-border-color="white" data-recommendations="false"></div></div>';
    }

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#show').click(function(){
            $('#feed').html(showFeed());

        });
    });
```

Can be tested here: http://jsfiddle.net/7cPDK/6/

Any idea how to achieve it?

PD: id like to do it like this (load it on demand: not load it on pageload and show on demand)

Comment: See the content of the `div` with the id `fb-root` (e.g. by adding css, see this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/7cPDK/7/)). I think it's an error-message from facebook.

Comment: aha.. weird.. any suggestion ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand this language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you only want to move the script to the click-handler:

1.) Cut the script from the html:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<a id="show" href="#">Show What facebook users share
<div id="feed"></div>
```

2.) Paste it into the click-handler and add removing the element with id `facebook-jssdk` first if exists:

```
$('#show').click(function(){
    $('#facebook-jssdk').remove();
    (function(d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/es_LA/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=82743675977";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
    $('#feed').html(showFeed());
});
```

Also see this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/7cPDK/11/).

Comment: please, try also to click the link twice in your example